# My RecyclerView Adapter cant send data after clicking onClick

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, bundle, instance, adapter

I set my Recycler View Adapters onClickListener like this;

```
private val onClicked = object :NotesAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
    override fun onClicked(notesId: Int) {

        var fragment = NotOlustur()
        var bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("noteId",notesId)
        fragment.arguments = bundle

        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_notlar_to_notOlustur)
    }

}
```

In another fragment, I am trying to take it like this;

```
    noteId = requireArguments().getInt("noteId", -1) // in onCreate()
```

And if I came here by clicking on adapter, so if "noteId" is bigger than -1 (I am doing updates and creates in the same fragment), I want to shape my fragment according to this id with this control;

```
    if (noteId != -1){

        launch {
            context?.let {
                var notes = NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().getSpecificNote(noteId)
                binding.title.setText(notes.title)
                binding.theNot.setText(notes.noteText)
                if (notes.imgPath != ""){
                    selectedImagePath = notes.imgPath!!
                    binding.background.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(notes.imgPath))
                    binding.background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }else{
                    binding.background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But im getting this error;

java.lang.IllegalStateException : FragmentNotOlustur does not have any arguments.

He was also using newInstance(), the youtube channel that published the tutorial for this code like this.

```
private val onClicked = object :NotesAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
    override fun onClicked(notesId: Int) {


        var fragment : Fragment
        var bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("noteId",notesId)
        fragment = NotOlustur.newInstance()
        fragment.arguments = bundle

        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_notlar_to_notOlustur)
    }

}
```

But I deleted it because it didn't work for me (I was constantly importing things with Alt + Enter, but it didn't work) and I think I did it wrong. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a Fragment instance and doing nothing with it. It's freed to the garbage collector and then you are using the nav controller to navigate to your destination. The navigation controller will create the Fragment that it navigates to.

So, you should pass your bundle to the `navigate()` function, not the throwaway fragment that you created.

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putInt("noteId",notesId)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_notlar_to_notOlustur, bundle)
```

By the way, you can use `bundleOf` for more concise syntax.

```
val bundle = bundleOf("noteId" to notesId)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_notlar_to_notOlustur, bundle)
```